# ggplot puts bended segments upon map created with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm plotting a geom_segment upon a map using ggmap in the following code:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

data <- data.frame(point=c("One"), latitude=c(-20),longitude=c(-25), latitude_end=c(50),longitude_end=c(50),sample=c("One"))

map <- get_map(location=c(-20,-10,55,30), zoom = 3, maptype = "terrain", scale = 2)

p0 <- ggmap(map, size=c(100, 200), extent="device", legend="bottom")
p1 <- p0 +
geom_segment(data=data, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, xend=longitude_end, yend=latitude_end), 
           colour="black") +
geom_point(data = data, aes(x =longitude, y = latitude), size=3,shape = 16)
png("plot.png")
p1
dev.off()
```

[image]

The bend is slight, look carefully and you will notice it is there (or put something straight on your monitor), which creates a horrible aesthetic effect once more lines are added. Is it possible to force a straight line on top of the map?

Sidenote: Is it also possible to embed a vignette with the text at end extreme with some text (data$sample)?

Comment: A "staight line" over that distance is a great circle route, which will not appear straight in this or most other projections